# Safest option for resizing /home and merging newly freed space with existing free space to form shared partition

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, gparted

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 installed in the dual-boot mode along with Windows 10, and here is my current partition setup.

[image]

What I'd like to do is install Ubuntu 18.04.3 afresh while resizing my /home partition to, say, 4 GB (is this a reasonable size? I do not plan on storing any large files such as audio/video ones) and then combining the freed space with the 2.36 GB currently unallocated to create a shared NTFS partition.

What is my best (safest) course of action? Should I carry out the partition resizing and partition creation steps before I install Ubuntu 18.04.3? I believe I can do this by booting using a gparted live USB. Then, I could just install 18.04.3 on the existing / partition while formatting it and the newly resized /home. Is this the right way to do it?

Or will I get a chance to make these changes at the time of the installation of the OS? I have not clicked beyond this screen during the installation process and do not whether the above will be an option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your root and /home exceed 13GB right now. 4GB is not adequate for the Ubuntu OS and its swap file. I'd make it 30 GB to allow room for growth, or at the least, 20 GB.

Fortunately you can do this without robbing any space from Windows, since you can eliminate your swap partition in the process. When the installer comes to disk allocation, choose **Something Else** and you can delete p5, p6, and p7, then create one new partition p5 which picks up all their space plus the 2.4GB of free space.

Comment: I'd only be resizing the /home partition from 7 GB to 4/5 GB. The / partition would remain at ~27 GB and the swap at ~16 GB. Would that not be enough?

Comment: Unless hibernating you do not need a swap partition. Default install is to use a swap file (like Windows has). If you have a swap partition it will be used. And if not having a large /home partition better to just keep everything in /. I use 25GB or 30GB for / and have 100's of GB just for data. But no large media file or games.

Comment: @Anonymouse  If you don't hibernate, you don't need a swap partition. However, I would keep /home and root consolidated in one partition as when you add apps, somtimes they take space in /home.